# IF Statement not working correctly

Tags: javascript

I have these controls:

```
    chck1_amt through chck5_amt (1 though 5 check Amounts)

    And chckX is from chcknum1 through chcknum5 (1 through 5 check numbers
```

What we are trying to do is if a checkX_amt box has is not blank or it has a value other than a 0 AND check number box (chcknumX) is blank, then inform a user that check number box must contain a check number. Stay focused on that box till the user has entered a checknumber.

This *appeared* to have worked until today when it keeps asking for check number whether there is a value in checkamount box or not.

Here's the code:

```js
if ((document.getElementById('chck1_amt').value != "" || document.getElementById('chck1_amt').value != "0") && (document.getElementById('fvEmp_chcknum1').value == "")) {
    alert("Please enter check # to continue");
    document.getElementById('chcknum1').focus();
    return false;
}
if (((document.getElementById('chck2_amt').value != "") || (document.getElementById('chck2_amt').value != "0")) && (document.getElementById('fvEmp_chcknum2').value == "")) {
    alert("Please enter check # to continue");
    document.getElementById('chcknum2').focus();
    return false;
}
if ((document.getElementById('chck3_amt').value != "0") && (document.getElementById('chcknum3').value == "")) {
    alert("Please enter check # to continue");
    document.getElementById('chcknum3').focus();
    return false;
}
if ((document.getElementById('chck4_amt').value != "0") && (document.getElementById('chcknum4').value == "")) {
    alert("Please enter check # to continue");
    document.getElementById('chcknum4').focus();
    return false;
}
if ((document.getElementById('chck5_amt').value != "0") && (document.getElementById('chcknum5').value == "")) {
    alert("Please enter check # to continue");
    document.getElementById('chcknum5').focus();
    return false;
}
```

```html
<tr>
    <td><input name="chcknum1" type="text" id="chcknum1" style="width:90px;" /></td><td><input name="chck1_amt" type="text" id="chck1_amt" style="width:90px;" /></td><td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input name="chcknum2" type="text" id="chcknum2" style="width:90px;" /></td><td><input name="chck2_amt" type="text" id="chck2_amt" style="width:90px;" /></td><td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input name="chcknum3" type="text" id="chcknum3" style="width:90px;" /></td><td><input name="chck3_amt" type="text" id="chck3_amt" style="width:90px;" /></td><td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input name="chcknum4" type="text" id="chcknum4" style="width:90px;" /></td><td><input name="chck4_amt" type="text" id="chck4_amt" style="width:90px;" /></td><td>
</tr><tr>
    <td><input name="chcknum5" type="text" id="chcknum5" style="width:90px;" /></td><td><input name="chck5_amt" type="text" id="chck5_amt" style="width:90px;" /></td><td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I have tried to use Firebug to see what is going on?

Comment: The HTML would help - just for the first `if` statement. The other statements are superflous for the demonstration of the problem

Comment: Ed, I have updated my original post above with html tags. Pls. let me know if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('chck1_amt').value && Number(document.getElementById('chck1_amt').value) && !document.getElementById('chcknum1').value && !Number(document.getElementById('chcknum1').value)) {
  alert('Check 1 has an amount but does not have a valid check number');
  document.getElementById('chcknum1').focus();
  return false;
}
```

etc

Comment: James, thanks alot for your response. It *ALMOST* worked. The problem is that given the way the code was written (by someone else who is no longer here), after entering value for the first box, the rest fill with 0 automatically. That's why I am trying to validate both blank and 0.

Comment: Yes, I was incorrectly assuming that a value of "0" would be falsy.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but it looks like your logic is backwards, as anything *other* than `""` or `"0"` will prompt the user to enter a check number. Shouldn't the condition be something like this?:

**EDIT**

Thanks for your comment. I understand your question now. I still think that there is an issue with your logic though. If the user should be prompted for input when the value is anything other than `""` or `0`, the logic should be like this:

```
if (document.getElementById('chck5_amt').value.trim() != "0" && document.getElementById('chck5_amt').value.trim() != ""){
    //prompt for check number
}
```

You might want to add some additional checks to make sure that the input boxes are being found:

```
var input = document.getElementById('chck5_amt');

//uncomment the line below to validate that the input was found
//alert(input);

if (input){
    if (input.value.trim() != "0" && input.value.trim() != ""){
        //prompt for check number
    }
}
```

Comment: No, let me try in plain english. Perhaps, I am not doing a good job of explaining it. If check amount box is 0 or it is blank as in your example then no need to require a user to enter check number. However, if checkamount box is not blank and it is not 0 then a user is required to enter check number. sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I *may* have discovered the problem. If checkamount box is either blank or 0, then no need to require that check number NOT be blank.